# What are the pre-conditions of reading SICP?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, scheme, sicp

right now i have got suggestions like "Simply scheme" and "The little schemer".
what others are available?

Comment: Ability to read, curiosity, and sufficient motivation to struggle through and let it expand your mind.

Comment: It's supposed to be an introductory level text. If you're willing to try even a little, just dive right in.

Comment: It's far from being "an introductory text" in the sense that you just need to be able to read and a little motivation.  IMO it's a fine question and one that should not have been closed as off-topic.

Comment: [The original McCarthy paper](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive.html); "Lisp 1.5 manual"; "the Lambda papers" by Guy Steel/Gerald Sussman is all excellent stuff. (anything quoted is googlable). Also, "the Funarg problem". Not *pre*-conditions, just excellent read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't programmed before in Scheme, then start with the easier books. Sorted from easier to harder:

1. The Little Schemer
2. Simply Scheme
3. SICP

For any of them, it helps to have a decent mathematical and logical intuition, and a lot of curiosity and motivation to learn by yourself.

Comment: Not that it matters, but this is not really a good list.  TLS is not as easy as you make it sound, and simply scheme has some weird ideas on code.  Also, HtDP is glaringly missing from it.